# How to read the property values of the viewport meta tag?

Tags: javascript, meta

I have tried:

```
var viewportElement = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]'),
    viewPort = {};

if (viewportElement) {
    viewportElement.content.split(',').forEach(function (property) {
        property = property.split('=');
        viewPort[property[0]] = property[1];
    });
}

console.log(viewPort);
```

It does give the expected result:

```
Object {width: "320", user-scalable: "no"}
```

However, I am not sure if reading values of these properties from the tag attribute value is the correct approach. I am expecting that these properties are hiding somewhere under the `window`?

Comment: I suppose nothing is wrong with reading meta properties directly from `<meta>`. It is quite simple to do it: `document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').getAttribute("user-scalable")`. If attribute doesn't contain specials chars, it is even more simple: `document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').width`.

Comment: Your syntax is not going to work. You are getting attribute value, not value of a property set in that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This will get what you need...

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').getAttribute("content").split(',')[0].split('=')[1]
```